# Последовательность выполнения условий в Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Какой из этих запросов более правильный и почему?

```
-- Первый запрос
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.date > '2019-01-01' and t1.sum < 1000

-- Второй запрос
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t1.date > '2019-01-01' and t1.sum < 1000
```

Насколько я понимаю, в первом варианте сначала table1 сократится условием where, и уже к оставшейся части таблицы будет применен join. При построении запросов с join использование where является обязательным?

P.S. Sql Server 2012 года.

Comment: Это два идентичных запроса, для INNER JOIN-а не имеет значения расположены условия в секции JOIN или в секции WHERE.

Comment: Вообще говоря, нет никакой закрепленной последовательности выполнения условий в операторах SQL. Вы говорите серверу ЧТО нужно получить, а сервер определяет КАК. Например, если в Вашем запросе в таблице table2 одна строка, то сначала будет читаться она и к ней будет джойниться table1, хотя в самом запросе написано наоборот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения плана выполнения запросы идентичный. У MS SQL версии 2005 об этом было явно написано в справке по INNER JOIN.

К тому же до введения ключевого слова JOIN в стандарт SQL этот же запрос выглядел так:

```
select *
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t2.id = t1.id and t1.date > '2019-01-01' and t1.sum < 1000
```

Но первый запрос чуть легче понять, потому что условие соединение, являющееся чисто технической деталью, отделено от условия отсева, продиктованного бизнес-логикой.

PS чтобы такие вопросы не возникали, советую научиться пользоваться инструментом [live query statistic](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/live-query-statistics?view=sql-server-2017)